# When printing string why I am getting warning when constant qualifier not used in c?

Tags: c, string, printf

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  const char arr[10] = "hello";
  printf(arr);
  return 0;
}
```

When compiling the above code with don't gave any warning. But when I remove the
`const` from `const char arr[10]` it gives a warning:

```
<source>: In function 'main':
<source>:5:10: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
    5 |   printf(arr);
      |
```

Why I am getting like this? How the `const` keyword make difference? Here I am compiling with `gcc -Wformat -Wformat-security …`.

Comment: You have enabled this warning using `-Wformat=2` or something like that

Comment: `man 3 printf` explains `int printf(const char *restrict format, ...);`

Comment: Non-reproducible in any version of gcc. Please include all compiler options used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But when I remove the `const` from `const char arr[10]` it gives warning
> like `format not a string literal and no format argument`. Why I am
> getting like this?

`printf()` *requires* you to provide a format string, and *allows* you to provide additional arguments as needed to match whatever conversion specifiers appear in the format.

It is risky, in general, to use a modifiable string as a `printf` format, because it may turn out to have unexpected conversion specifiers in it.  This is primarily an issue with data read at runtime, and your particular string would be ok, but GCC's warning doesn't look so deeply.  It just sees a modifiable string as a format and issues the warning.

Safer alternatives that will not draw a warning from gcc would include using `fputs()`:

```
    fputs(arr, stdout);
```

... and using `printf()` with an appropriate format:

```
  printf("%s", arr);
```

.

> How the `const` keyword make difference?

Apparently GCC does not distinguish between an array of `const char` and a string literal for this purpose.  That's not unreasonable, but it does make the diagnostic a little confusing.

Comment: "Apparently GCC does not distinguish between an array of const char and a string literal for this purpose. That's not unreasonable, but it does make the diagnostic a little confusing." Could you please explain little bit clear ? I have one more doubt, here when the  array of char considered as `const`, it is in compile time or run time ?

Comment: Still doesn't explain where the warning is coming from, since it is not reproducible with or without `const` in any version of gcc I tried.

Comment: @Baranitharan The array is created on the stack at runtime, but the string value is a constant stored in the data section just as all string literals. Since the array is const, it means that gcc should know that the array value is always the same as the string literal (but with additional padding), making it semantically the same as passing in the literal directly. I wouldn't be surprised if gcc would inline the string.

Comment: ... moreover, in the case presented, GCC could optimize out the array on the stack altogether, so that as compiled, it actually was a string literal used.

Answer (score 2):

While it's valid to pass a `char *` (which a `char` array decays to) to a function expecting a `const char *`, it's bad practice to pass something that's not a string constant as the first argument to `printf`, which is what the warning is about.

This argument is a format string that dictates how any additional arguments are processed.  If this first argument is not a string constant but something that the user can control, it opens up the possibility of passing in format specifiers that would process more arguments than were passed.  This can allow for reading memory that wasn't intended to be read or writing memory not intended to be written and is considered a security hole.

Comment: It's perfectly valid to pass a `T *` to a function expecting a `const T *`. Indeed, that would still be what happens if the OP passed a string literal as the `printf` format, as the diagnostic suggests they do, and as is utterly routine.  That's not what GCC is on about.  The diagnostic the OP received is GCC getting a little preachy about the `printf`-specific issue addressed in your last paragraph.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Guess I got my const-correctness backwards.  It's late...

Comment: Still doesn't explain where the warning is coming from, since it is not reproducible with or without `const` in any version of gcc I tried.